# Find the value of $\int_1^2\frac{x^2-1}{(x^2+1+3x)(x^2-x+1)}dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

Find the value of

$\int_1^2\frac{x^2-1}{(x^2+1+3x)(x^2-x+1)}dx$

I tried but it was failed. Can you help me!

Comment: The brute force method: separate into partial fractions. If you like complex numbers, then this becomes some logarithms. If you prefer to let irreducible quadratics stay, then a little arctrig might arise. Regardless, this approach will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: $\frac{x^2-1}{(x^2+1+3x)(x^2-x+1)}=\frac{2x+3}{x^2+3x+1}-\frac{2x-1}{x^2-x+1}$.

The solution is actually very clean now.

Comment: Sorry. It's $x^2-1$. Edited.

Comment: Edited. It actually makes sense to be $x^2-1$. It makes the problem has a much cleaner solution than it would be if it were $x^2+1$. Let me know if you can finish it by yourself